# Some questions on covering spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Let $A_{1}$ be the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=1, B_{1}$ be the circle $(x-2)^{2}+y^{2}=1, A_{2}$ be the circle $(x-4)^{2}+y^{2}=1$ and $B_{2}$ be the circle $(x+2)^{2}+y^{2}=1 .$

Define $\tilde{X}=A_{1} \cup B_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup B_{2}$
and $X=A_{1} \cup B_{1} .$ Define a map $p: \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ as follows:

i) $p(\cos (t), \sin (t))=(\cos (2 t), \sin (2 t))$ for $(\cos (t), \sin (t)) \in A_{1}$ (Circle $A_{1}$ wraps twice around
$\left.A_{1}\right)$

ii) $p(-\cos (t)+2, \sin (t))=(-\cos (2 t)+2, \sin (2 t))$ for $(-\cos (t)+2, \sin (t)) \in B_{1}$ (Circle $B_{1}$ wraps
twice around $B_{1}$ ),

iii) $\left.p\right|_{A_{2}},$ and $\left.p\right|_{B_{2}}$ is mapped homeomorphically onto $A_{1}$ and $B_{1}$ respectively.
Now $p$ is a covering map. (You do not need to prove this.)

a) Give a presentation for $\pi_{1}(\tilde{X},(1,0))$ and $\pi_{1}(X,(1,0))$. Carefully write down the generators.

b) Compute $p_{*}\left(\pi_{1}(\tilde{X},(1,0)\right)$ as a subgroup of $\pi_{1}(X,(1,0))$

c) Is $p_{*}\left(\pi_{1}(\tilde{X},(1,0)\right )$ a normal subgroup of $\pi_{1}(\tilde{X},(1,0)) ?$ Give reasons.

d) What is the automorphism group $A(\tilde{X}, p) ?$ Give reasons.

My try:

a) $\pi_1(X)=\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z=<a,b>(say)$ and $\pi_1(\tilde X)=\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z * \Bbb Z * \Bbb Z$

For part b) I don't know how to proceed.

c)

> If $p : (\tilde{X},\tilde{v}) \rightarrow (X,v)$ is a covering map. Then $p$ is regular if and only if any two points in $p^{-1}(v)$ differ by a covering transformation.

or

> If $p : (\tilde{X},\tilde{v}) \rightarrow (X,v)$ is a covering map. Then $p$ is regular if for any two points $\tilde{v}_{1}, \tilde{v}_{2}$  in $p^{-1}(v)$, a loop $\ell$ based at $v$ in $X$ lifts to a loop $\tilde{\ell}$ in $\tilde{X}$ based at $\tilde{v}_{1}$ if and only if it lifts to a loop in $\tilde{X}$ based at $\tilde{v}_{2}$.

Then, we know that $(\tilde{X},\tilde{v})$ is a regular covering space of $(X,v)$ if and only if $p_{*}(\pi_{1}(\tilde{X},\tilde{v}))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_{1}(X,v)$. Moreover we also have one to one correspondence between $C(\tilde{X}, p, X) \to N(H_0)/H_0$ where $H_0=p_{*}(\pi_1(\tilde{X},(1,0)))$ and $C(\tilde{X}, p, X)$ is the group of covering transformations and if $H_0$ is normal then we will have one to one correspondence between $C(\tilde{X}, p, X) \to \pi_1(X)/H_0$.

One footnote: I am reading Munkres basically and these are the questions depending on that. Hatcher will be a bit tough for me right now. Please give me a detailed explanation for part or full question. Then I will have an idea.

Comment: Where is figure 1?

Comment: I am sorry I draw the figure on my page using the functions but didn't upload it as this is on paper. You can draw the picture by your own $X$ is a wedge of 2 circles and $\tilde X$ is a wedge of 4 circles.